# Docker Compose env_file in Multicontainer Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, docker-compose

I have the following docker compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: >
      bash -cex "
        export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
        export LANG=C.UTF-8
        /virtualenv/bin/flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5050
      "
    env_file: env
    links:
    - postgres
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
```

As you can see I'm using the **env_file** option to load my environment variables from the file **env**.

Now I'm trying to deploy this container to Elastic Beanstalk.
This is my file Dockerrun.aws.json so far:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,

  "containerDefinitions": [

    {
      "name": "app",
      "image": "myorg/myimage",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 256,
      "command": [
        "/bin/bash",
        "export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8",
        "export LANG=C.UTF-8",
        "/virtualenv/bin/flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5050"
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "containerPort": 8080
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "postgres",
      ]
    }
```

In the AWS Elastic Beanstalk [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun) just mention the **environment** option to pass an array of env variables, but I can't find how to pass a file instead of an array of variables.

Does someone knows how to translate this **docker-compose** file to **Dockerrun.aws.json** file properly?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try [container-transform](https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform).

```
$ pip install container-transform
$ cat docker-compose.yml | container-transform  -v
```

and it will print the ECS format to STDOUT.